# Does Dunn's test (particularly the Z-statistic) say anything about direction?

Tags: kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

I have conducted a Dunn's test to compare the distribution of factor scores across three nominal variables. How do I interpret the signs of the Z-statistic? Do Z-statistics say anything about direction?